# FindBugs Ant task - how to load preferences file?

Tags: ant, preferences, findbugs

I run FindBugs from Ant task. I have preferences file .fbprefs which I want FindBugs to use, so that the bug report produced by Ant matches the one produced by Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the ant task is based on filter files, see http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/manual/filter.html

Answer (score 0):

You should start using filter files not the Eclipse plugin configuration. Check this resource: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Project+settings#Projectsettings-Excluderesources

It should help you create a filter which corresponds to your Eclipse FindBugs plugin configuration.